# Rails common gem version dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

What if my app have some dependencies with specific version, but uses other gem that requires the same dependency with previous version?

For example:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "other_gem":
  In Gemfile:
    first_gem depends on
      other_gem (~> 0.7.3)

    second_gem depends on
      other_gem (0.6.1)
```

What I am doing right now is forking a repo with this gem, changing version of dependency up to that I required and linking gem directly from GitHub.

Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: forking is usually the way to go, but watch out for potentially breaking changes in `other_gem`.